# Crashplan exit - what are the alternatives?

Tags: backup, owncloud

Crashplan stops with serving the consumer market. Current subscribers are supported for another 14 months. Up til now they had (in my view) the best offer with their Family Plan: unlimited backup for multiple computers for $14/month, with support for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Crashplan proposes Carbonite, but it doesn't offer Linux support and has no family plan.

At the moment I'm backing up three computers. What good alternatives are there for backing up securely online? I do have access to a 1TB online archive (Owncloud based).

Comment: "securely" and "online" don't go together with backups. Choose one and leave the other behind.

Comment: My computer is online. All my backups are "online". Backups can be encrypted. Nothing is 100% secure.

Comment: You could try S3, Glacier or Arctic. Probably your most secure option to be honest.

Comment: Certainly nothing is 100% secure. Encryption helps with privacy against some threats (as long as YOU perform it), but remember availability. Online means tht you need to have internet connection, to use your bandwidth and that the service needs to be available when you require it. And since the question is about an online service removing support, I think it's relevant to mention that whatever service you chose, it can also disapear when **they** want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popular alternative backup services typically charge per-computer. And while the family plan was extremely economical when backing up 5+ computers, there's really not much difference when only working with three:

- Backblaze: $50/computer/year (so, same cost as Crashplan for you). No Linux. 30 day file versioning.
- Carbonite: $59/computer/year (offering 50% discount for current Crashplan Home users). No Linux. File versioning on Windows client only, not Mac.
- CrashPlan for Business. $120/year/computer. Offering 75% discount for first year (beyond current subscription), for current Home subscribers, so... might be worth staying for one additional year, for you.

Note: Backblaze does offer their B2 service, which is a storage backend used in conjunction with local storage devices (e.g. NAS) or software (e.g. Cloudberry). Not exactly the same as the other backup solutions, but something to consider.

Comment: There is `backblaze-b2` for linux, and `rclone` supports backblaze too.